# Rails 3 find_or_create_by_slug sometimes creates duplicate records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Rails 3.2.14 with Ruby 2.1.0. I have a method which takes care of creating a user in DB by checking if the email id exists or not.

I use **devise** and **SAML** for user authentication and session creation.

I use the following code to do so:

```
@user = User.find_or_create_by_email(:email=>"xyz@gmail.com", firstname: 'XY', lastname: 'Z', code: 'ABC')
```

This works in most of the cases, but rest of the time I keep getting error notification emails in my account as the above code tries to create one more user with the same email:

```
An ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique occurred in sessions#consume:

  Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'xyz@gmail.com' for key 'email'
```

How I can avoid this error?

Comment: AR query seems to be incorrect. Shouldn't it be: `User.find_or_create_by_email("xyz@gmail.com")` ?

Comment: The query is correct, if the record is not present it creates the  user record with other fields as shown above.

Comment: try this: `@user = User.find_or_create_by_email(...) rescue User.find_by_email(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like [Upsert](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert)

`find_or_create` will first run `SELECT` and then `INSERT`. Another instance could have run the `INSERT` in between. You could also maybe use a transaction:

```
User.transaction do 
  @user = User.find_or_create_by_email(:email=>"xyz@gmail.com", firstname: 'XY', lastname: 'Z', code: 'ABC')
end
```

Comment: Can using a transaction alone be enough?

Comment: Yes it should work. I'm not entirely sure if a transaction solves that but I suspect it might.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had implemented the previous method which you had suggested `find_by_email || create` with Transaction. Now I am not getting any more errors.